# Why does Replace sometimes don't work?

Tags: replacement

I am trying to do this **replacement**, but it didn't work, WHY?!
Please any idea how to solve it

```
Replace[(Z (X + Y) Cos[2 ϕ]),Cos[2 ϕ] -> 1 - 2 Sin[ϕ]^2]
```

Comment: Try `Replace[(Z (X + Y) Cos[2 \[Phi]]), 
 Cos[2 \[Phi]] -> 1 - 2 Sin[\[Phi]]^2, 1]`

Comment: Because `Replace` only works by default at the level of the *whole* expression.  Try `ReplaceAll` instead.

Comment: @QuantumDot, it works now, thanx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is because `Replace` only works at level 0 in the expression.

For expample:

```
Replace[a , a -> b]
(* b *)
```

but

```
Replace[a + 1, a -> b]
(* 1 + a *)
```

This is because the expression `a + 1` is, in fact, `Plus[a,1]`, and `a` doesn't appear at level 0 in the expression, but at level 1 (that is, as an argument of a function that appears in the expression at level 0).

However, the function `Replace` allows us to specify up to which level we want it to search in the expresion:

```
Replace[a + 1, a -> b, 1]
(* 1 + b *)
```

But I find more useful for general usage in mathematical expressions the function `ReplaceAll`, which searches up to level infinity

```
ReplaceAll[a + 1, a -> b]
(* 1 + b *)
```

or with its shortened syntax,

```
a + 1 /. a -> b
(* 1 + b *)
```

As a side note I will say that `Replace[expr,rule,∞]` is not the same as `ReplaceAll[expr,rule]`. `Replace` searches from subexpressions to greater expressions, and `ReplaceAll` does the other way around.

So you can solve you problem just with

```
ReplaceAll[(Z (X + Y) Cos[2 ϕ]),Cos[2 ϕ] -> 1 - 2 Sin[ϕ]^2]
(* (X + Y) Z (1 - 2 Sin[ϕ]^2) *)
```

**Comment**

If you don't understand what I mean with *level* in the expression, look this tree graph that I have obtained with the function `TreeForm` of the expression `a^2 + b^2`. It tells us that at level 0, what we have is an expression with header `Plus`, and its arguments are the next elements (`Power[a,b]` and `Power[b,2]`), which are at level 1. `a` and `b` are at level 2.

[image: Tree graph]

**More comments**

As @corey979 mentions, the possibility of level specification in the function `Replace` gives us some interesting possibilities, for example:

```
Replace[Log[a + a^2], a -> x, {0, 2}]
(* Log[a^2 + x] *)
```

The level specification tells the function to search *only* at levels from 0 to 2. `a` appears at level 2 (inside the `Plus`) and at level 3 (inside the `Power`), so only the former will be replaced.

[image: Tree graph]

Comment: This answer in SO is much more precise and complete than mine, by the way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6836972/6730818

Comment: There are also constructs like `Replace[Log[a + a^2], a -> x, {0, 2}]` which you might want to mention. And give a solution to the OP's problem (i.e., how to `Cos[2 ϕ] -> 1 - 2 Sin[ϕ]^2`).

Comment: @corey979 Yes, I thought about it, but my intention was not give an exhaustive explanation about the functions, but a little didactic insight for OP. But now that you mention it, I will add it, because in fact I found it very interesting.